# Como resolver aviso de header information

Tags: php

Como eu posso resolver esse aviso? Nunca vi na minha vida, no meu servidor local (localhost) não dá esse aviso, só no servidor da hospedagem...

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lostscav/public_html/quiz/questao.php:25) in /home/lostscav/public_html/quiz/questao.php on line 30**

A linha 30 é essa dentro do else

```
// $posicoes = isset($_SESSION['respostas']) ? count($_SESSION['respostas']) : 0;
$posicoes = count($_SESSION['respostas']);
echo $posicoes;
if ($_GET['idQuestao'] > $posicoes) {
    //echo "n acontece nada!";
} else {
    $voltaQuestao = $idQuestao + 1;
    header("Location: questao.php?idQuestao=" . $voltaQuestao); // LINHA 30
}

if ($idQuestao > 10) {
    header("Location: resultados.php");
}
```

Comment: Não consegui...

Comment: resumindo, você não pode fazer um `echo` e depois tentar aplicar um `header()`, pois ele deve vir sempre antes de qualquer tipo de saída...